# SearchBox Multi Match Query with type best_fields and NOT phrase_prefix

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch, searchkit

I am using *SearchBox* from searchkit 2.2.0 and would like to make *Multi Match Query* with  option *type best_fields* to elasticsearch.

1. How to set *type best_fields* when I use *prefixQueryFields*?
2. How to correctly set *prefixQueryOptions* object with *type best_fields*?

If I set *prefixQueryFields* attribute, query is Multi Match as I want, but type is phrase_prefix gets me non prefered results.
[QueryAccessor.ts->this.options.prefixQueryFields->type:"phrase_prefix"](https://github.com/searchkit/searchkit/blob/master/src/core/accessors/QueryAccessor.ts)

```html
<SearchBox autofocus={true} searchOnChange={true} prefixQueryFields={["fileName^3", "path", "attachment.content", "attachment.author", "attachment.title"]}/>
```

[image: result query: prefixQueryFields and type phrase_prefix]

If I set *prefixQueryOptions* attribute, to avoid type phrase_prefix, query become just simple_query_string. Maybe I made a mistake here, when I set *prefixQueryOptions* object.

```html
<SearchBox autofocus={true} searchOnChange={true} prefixQueryOptions={{
    "fields" : [ "fileName^3", "path", "attachment.content", "attachment.author", "attachment.title" ],
    "type":       "best_fields"
   }}/>
```

[image: result query: prefixQueryOptions and simple_query_string]

[search-box](http://docs.searchkit.co/v2.0.0/components/basics/search-box.html)

[multi-match-types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#multi-match-types)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*queryBuilder* can provide more flexible logic than *prefixQueryFields*.
https://blog.searchkit.co/searchkit-0-9-23d78568d219

```html
const customQueryBuilder = (query, options) => {
  return {
    "multi_match": {
   "query": query,
   "fields" : [ "fileName^3", "path", "attachment.content", "attachment.author", "attachment.title" ],
   "type":       "best_fields"
 }
  }
}

<SearchBox autofocus={true} searchOnChange={true} queryOptions={{analyzer:"standard"}} queryFields={["fileName^3","path","attachment.content","attachment.author","attachment.title","attachment.fileExtension"]} queryBuilder={customQueryBuilder} />
```

[image]