# can I implement partial search for search results in hits for searchbox of searchkit

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch, searchkit

I am working on searchkit and I am trying to get the results on partial search for search in searchbox,but the results are available when complete text is matched in database.Is there a way to implement this,I have tried 
**queryOptions={{analyzer: "patrial", default_operator:"AND", allow_leading_wildcard: true, analyze_wildcard: true}}**
in my searchbox tag,but it gives error while searching.
This is my code of searchbox:

```
        ** <SearchBox
                    translations={{"searchbox.placeholder":" "}}
                    autofocus={true}
                                searchOnChange={true}
                                // queryOptions= 
                    {{default_operator:"AND"}}
                                queryOptions={{analyzer: "patrial", 
                     default_operator:"AND", allow_leading_wildcard: 
                       true, analyze_wildcard: true}}

                                />**
```

Comment: Is `patrial` a typo for `partial`?  It's in both your text and code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Custom Query in the `queryBuilder` of the `SearchBox` component as mentioned in: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46685463/searchbox-multi-match-query-with-type-best-fields-and-not-phrase-prefix)

```
const customQueryBuilder = (query, options) => {
  return {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": query,
      "fields" : [ "field1", "field2", "field3"]
  }
  }
}

<SearchBox queryBuilder={customQueryBuilder} autofocus={true}  queryOptions={{analyzer:"autocomplete", searchOnChange={true} prefixQueryFields={["field1", "field2", "field3"]}  />
```